# Got a work offer but asked for my first visa digits

Tags: credit-card, canada, scams, visa, working-abroad

I live in Lebanon and I made an account on Linkedin.  I got a work offer from a company from Canada.  They asked me questions about my education, marital status and if I have 12,000$ in my account to support myself if I were to go to Canada.  They  asked if I have a credit card as well as  what the first 6 digits are.

Why  would they ask for the first 6 digits and is it safe to give him those digits?

Comment: That's a lot of digits for a 10-11 digit number. Everything else seems legit-ish (unless they're asking you to TRANSFER any of that money, then its not), but I'd be worried about them requiring so many digits from such a short number. I don't know enough myself to help out though. :/

Comment: The first six digits of a MasterCard or Visa card identify the institution that issued the card and what kind of card it is (debit or credit), as well as any special properties or restrictions (cf. [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/29780/5760)), and so your prospective employer is wanting these numbers to get this information. E.g., some debit cards issued in India are valid only for charges made in Indian rupees, and if your Lebanese debit card has a similar restriction to Lebanon, then the $12,000 is useless as far as your using it to support yourself in Canada is concerned.

Comment: Why does it matter that it's in a Visa card? I know Canada has proof-of-fund requirements for certain (immigration) visas, but what they need is a [letter from the bank](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html). Sounds like a eventual scam to me.

Comment: Is this not about an immigration visa number?

Comment: They are the ones paying you (if and when you are employed with them), so why would they ask how much money you have in your account now? Seems like scam to me. Did they contact you or you contacted them first? Why would a company in Canada want to hire someone residing in a different country, as opposed to finding a candidate locally? None of this looks like a normal job offer.

Comment: When you say you "got a work offer from a company in Canada," do you mean you *applied for this job* and got a response, or do you mean someone sent you an email out of the blue?

Comment: i got almost same issue. I tried to apply a visa in canada via online. He then call me and ask a same questions. He also ask the first 6 digits. Im scared that if this guy know my first digits and verified the bank, maybe he can take a money from my card. Is it safe to just giveaway your first 6 digits?

Comment: Few hours ago I received phone call from Australia and they asked about exactly same thing and I just gave my Visa card first six digits and after hours I just got worried about what I did and now I’m here.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a scam to me. The first 6 digits of a Visa card number identify the issuing bank, who they can now call, and armed with the other identifying information you have given them, can try to social engineer into transferring money out of your accounts.

You should look in a reputable Canadian phone directory for the main office number for the company you think you're talking to, and call them to see if the person you've been emailing there actually exists, works there, and has the authority to offer you a job. I also think you'll find that immigrating to Canada is a lot more involved and drawn out (some people wait years) than the process you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Its a scam: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/12/thieves-can-guess-your-secret-visa-card-details-in-just-seconds/

> The numbers can also be inferred by combining your first six digits—which are based on the card brand, issuing bank, and card type—with a verification formula known as the Luhn Algorithm.